# CSS Navigation Bar Active Link

Tags: html, css, web, navigation

I'm creating a website, and currently I am having issues with my navigation bar. The issue I am having is with the active link. The background won't fit to the size of the initial button like I want it to. The background is just highlighting the text basically.

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="cage-habitat.html">Cage &amp; Habitat</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="litter-train-chinchilla.html">Litter Training</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="food-treats.html">Food &amp; Treats</a></li>
    <li><a href="dust-bath.html">Dust Bath &amp; Care</a></li>
    <li><a href="toys.html">Safe Toys</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Chinquiry</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```css
    .nav {
 background-color: #526655;
    }

    .nav a {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
    }

    .nav ul {
   text-align: left;
   display: inline;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
   list-style: none;
    }
    .nav ul li {
   color: #fff;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right: -4px;
   position: relative;
   padding: 15px 20px;
   background: #526655;
   cursor: pointer;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
   -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s;
   transition: all 0.2s;
    }
    .nav ul li:hover {
 background: #94b399;
   color: #fff;
}
 /* drop down styles */
 .nav ul li ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 42px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -transition: opacity 0.2s;
 }
 .nav ul li ul li { 
    background: #94b399; 
    display: block; 
    color: #fff;
 }
 .nav ul li ul li:hover { 
  background: #94b399; 
 }
 .nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
 }
 /* end dropdown styles */
    .active { 
 background: #94b399; 
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. https://jsfiddle.net/cweav3r/7j25e8jh/

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  <ul><li><a href="litter-train-chinchilla.html">Litter
>  Training</a></li></ul> is taking extra space .
> ```

```
DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/b89kds70/10/
       <div class="nav">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="active" href="cage-habitat.html">Cage &amp; Habitat</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="food-treats.html">Food &amp; Treats</a></li>
                <li><a href="dust-bath.html">Dust Bath &amp; Care</a></li>
                <li><a href="toys.html">Safe Toys</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Chinquiry</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>

 .nav {
    background-color: #526655;
    }

    .nav a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    .nav ul {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
    list-style: none;
    position:relative;
    }
    .nav ul li {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    background: #526655;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    }
    .nav ul li:hover {
    background: #94b399;
    color: #fff;
}
    /* drop down styles */
    .nav ul li ul {
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        top: 42px;
        left: 0;
        width: 150px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
        -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
        -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
        -transition: opacity 0.2s;
    }
    .nav ul li ul li { 
        background: #94b399; 
        display: inline;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .nav ul li ul li:hover { 
        background: #94b399; 
    }
    .nav ul li:hover ul {
        position:absolute;
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    /* end dropdown styles */
```

Comment: That didn't do anything to help with my question. The link that you said takes up space is for drop down navigation under cages. What I needed help with is making the background of the active link fit the container on the navigation bar rather than having it look like it is merely highlighting the text.